# Silverlight: How to move items in ItemsControl in Canvas

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, canvas, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl which shows a UserControl as an ItemTemplate. It has a Canvas ItemsPanel.

```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}" Margin="200,20,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MyControl Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Height="2000" Width="2000"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I want to move the controls over the Canvas on Mouse drag

MyControl has a Behavior:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl">

    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid Background="LightBlue" Height="20">
    </StackPanel>
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Behavior:DragControlBehavior />
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</UserControl>
```

DragControlBehavior sets the Canvas attached properties on MouseMove over the control

**[Update]** - Here is the full source code of the Behavior

```
public class DragControlBehavior : Behavior<MyControl>
{
    private DependencyObject _parent;
    private bool _isMouseCaptured = false;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _isMouseCaptured = true;
        };

        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _isMouseCaptured = false;
        };

        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (_isMouseCaptured)
            {
                if (_parent == null)
                {
                    _parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(AssociatedObject);
                    while (_parent.GetType() != typeof(Canvas))
                        _parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(_parent);
                }
                var pointOnCanvas = e.GetPosition((Canvas)_parent);
                Canvas.SetTop(AssociatedObject, pointOnCanvas.Y);
                Canvas.SetLeft(AssociatedObject, pointOnCanvas.X);
            }
        };
    }
```

If I use an instance of MyControl seperately on a Canvas it works but if there is a collection of MyControls in ItemsControl, they do not move on MouseMove

In WPF, I would use ItemContainerStyle but in SL it is not available:

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Can you show us the full source code of your `DragControlBehavior` class?  Without that it's difficult for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Full source code of the Behavior attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an `ItemsControl`, each item generated is wrapped in a `ContentPresenter`.  The visual tree looks a bit like the following:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl
  System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter
    System.Windows.Controls.Canvas
      System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter
        DragControlBehaviorTest.MyControl
          ...
```

(`DragControlBehaviorTest` is the name of the project I created to try your code out in.)

The `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties only work on direct children of the `Canvas`. If you place a `MyControl` directly in a `Canvas`, then your `MyControl` is a child of the `Canvas`, and so setting `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` on it will work.  However, if you're using an `ItemsControl` to generate your `MyControl`s, there is a `ContentPresenter` between the `Canvas` and each of your `MyControl`s.  You need to set the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties on these `ContentPresenters` instead.

You have a loop that runs from the `AssociatedObject` up the visual tree to find the ancestor `Canvas`.  You can modify this to find the immediate child of the canvas, using something like the following:

```
            _immediateChild = AssociatedObject;
            _parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(AssociatedObject);
            while (_parent.GetType() != typeof(Canvas))
            {
                _immediateChild = _parent;
                _parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(_parent);
            }
```